# Firebase vs Google Analytics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have installed Firebase to my Android and iOS apps, I can check the stats on computer, but can't check them on my iphone Google analytics app. Is there any way or app where can I check the stats or do I need to install also Google analytics to my apps as well?

Comment: Firebase and Google Analytics are totally two different services. I would suggest you to use only Google analytics, as I find it better.

Comment: Check this document http://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/featurebrief_mix-and-match-analytics-and-firebase-analytics-to-fit-the-needs-of-your-business.pdf

Answer (score 2):

When you use Google Analytics for Firebase (formerly known as Firebase Analytics) the analytics results show up in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/analytics/app/_/overview). They do not (currently) show up in the Google Analytics dashboard.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that they are two different things, but is there any way to check Firebase stats on phone as well, or just use Google analytics and forget about Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Firebase view in GA : it's just a webview of your firebase Console in GA (so the FiB and GA data are not mixed at all).

Another solution is to use a GTM container to send and convert your FiB event into GA data.

Here is the documentation for this process :

[iOS](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/)

[Android](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/)