# Firebase Warning to use firebase-core library when using firebase-messaging library

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I am using `firebase:firebase-messaging` library for push notification.
 While building the application I am seeing a warning which says

```
Warning: The app Gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.
```

Release notes by firebase say
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_23_2018

```
Firebase now requires the app Gradle file to explicitly list com.google.firebase:firebase-core as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.
```

Firebase-core library is used for analytics, what will happen if I don't include this library? I am already using `gms:play-services-analytics`. 
 
Also, I have found the library version for both `gms:play-services-analytics` must be the same as `firebase:firebase-core` library to avoid any build error.

Something like below

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Will there be any impact on the application if I will include `firebase:firebase-core` library in application gradle along with `gms:play-services-analytics`?

Why firebase is showing the above warning ? 
What will be impacted if I don't include `firebase-core` with `firebase-messaging` library? A warning can be ignored? 
Is this due to firebase adding analytics for all its features? 
Here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6383877?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't include `com.google.firebase:firebase-core`, then you won't be able to use the other firebase services like `firebase-database` or `firebase-messaging`.

If you are using `google-service` version `3.2.1+`, then you can use different library versions for `gms:play-services-analytics` and `firebase:firebase-core`.

Comment: if `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` is a hard dependency then why android is showing warning instead of an error ? 
PS : i have been using `firebase-messaging` without `firebase-core` but i didn't find any issue, until i saw the warning.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765554/is-firebase-core-required-for-firebase-on-android/50765555#comment91199367_50765555

Comment: Have you checked the link?

Comment: I am using `google-service:4.0.0` but when i use different versions of `gms:play-services-analytics` and `firebase:firebase-core` it throws error 
`Error: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzsp`.
`

[NOTE] Above error is not thrown incase of using same versions of both library

Comment: Yes the `core` and `google analytics` should be the same version and that's because the `firebase core` contains the `firebase analytics` library, which is the same as the `google service analytics` library. The only difference is that you can see your report in the firebase console, when you use firebase analytics. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842573/firebase-vs-google-analytics and this https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7388022?hl=en

Comment: So, if i include `firebase-core`. it will show some analytics data on the `firebase-console` ? what if i don't want any analytics data just want to use `firebase-messaging` and not include the `firebase-core` library. Can i ignore the warning ?

Comment: no I mean if you include `firebase-core` and configure the `firebase analytics`, it will show the analytics in the `firebase console`, if you don't configure firebase analytics it won't show data in the firebase console. If you just add `firebase-core` and `google-analytics`, then the data would be at `google analytics`. Also, yes you can ignore the warning, if you only want to use `firebase-messaging`